# Where does the idiom « Elle est à cheval sur les détails » come from?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

I got this phrase from a Duolingo lesson question, which suggests this translates to "She is a stickler for the details".

A comment on [the discussion](https://forum.duolingo.com/comment/27929906/Elle-est-%C3%A0-cheval-sur-les-d%C3%A9tails) for the question states that:

> It's an idiom. **être à cheval sur …** means "to be very serious and picky on…"

but a request for the source of the idiom has gone unanswered.

Where does this idiom come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most complete webpage that I know about French expressions is:

http://www.expressio.fr/toutes_les_expressions.php

For your particular expression:

> Etre à cheval sur... Être très exigeant, très strict sur... Attacher
> une grande importance, tenir rigoureusement à...
>
> Origine
>
> Il est certain qu'un cavalier est à cheval sur... son cheval.
> Et on peut, sans crainte de se tromper, affirmer qu'il attache une
> grande importance à sa monture. Mais est-ce que cela suffit à
> expliquer notre expression ?
>
> Eh bien nous n'en sommes pas loin ! Ceux qui sont si exigeants sur
> diverses choses que sont les principes, les règles ou l'orthographe,
> par exemple, sont des gens qui sont supposés bien les connaître et qui
> n'admettent pas qu'on s'en écarte ou les maltraite. Ne peut-on en dire
> autant du cavalier vis-à-vis de sa monture[1] ? Et quand on voit des
> écoles comme le Cadre Noir de Saumur (Lien externe) où les chevaux
> montés doivent apprendre à faire différents sauts, l'écuyer
> n'utilisant pas d'étriers, celui-ci ne doit-il pas être aussi
> fermement 'attaché' à son cheval que d'autres le sont à la qualité de
> l'orthographe ou au respect des principes ?
>
> Voilà autant d'images venues du monde équestre qui se sont répandues
> dans la vie de tous les jours pour donner naissance à notre expression
> dont la date d'apparition ne semble pas être exactement connue mais
> qui est citée par la version de 1832 du Dictionnaire de l'Académie
> Française.

Reference:

http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/etre-a-cheval-sur.php

Comment: Also thanks for that source. I can see myself making extensive use of that.

Answer (score 2):

It came from horse riding of course. As the jumps we taught to the houses are very strict! It means very demanding:

> L'expression vient de l'équitation. En effet, dans cette discipline les sauts et les pas appris aux chevaux sont très stricts, d'où le sens de l'expression "être à cheval sur..." qui signifie "être très pointilleux".

Take a look here:

http://www.linternaute.fr/expression/langue-francaise/4970/etre-a-cheval-sur/

https://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-definition/%c3%a0%20cheval%20sur